# Make PostgreSQL script idempotent by removing database and user before creating new ones

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

I have the following two functions:

```
drop_linked_resources() {
  local readonly host="$1"
  local readonly master_username="$2"
  local readonly master_password="$3"
  local readonly username="$4"
  local readonly password="$5"
  local readonly db="$6"

  docker run --rm \
    -e PGPASSWORD="$master_password" \
    postgres:9.6.3-alpine psql -h "$host" -d postgres -U "$master_username" <<-EOSQL
        DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $db;
        DROP USER IF EXISTS $username;
    EOSQL
}

create_user() {
  local readonly host="$1"
  local readonly master_username="$2"
  local readonly master_password="$3"
  local readonly username="$4"
  local readonly password="$5"
  local readonly db="$6"

  docker run --rm \
    -e PGPASSWORD="$master_password" \
    postgres:9.6.3-alpine psql -h "$host" -d postgres -U "$master_username" \
    -c "CREATE USER $username WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$password';"
}
```

very easy functions. `drop_linked_resources` run first to clean and after `create_user` runs. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
2018-03-20 16:21:56 [INFO] [create-database.sh] Drop linked existing resources
2018-03-20 16:21:57 [INFO] [create-database.sh] Create my_user user
role "my_user" already exists
```

I get this error because I run already the functions so in order to make it idempotent I must clean it and then create again.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Random note: I don’t think `local readonly` works in bash, you have to use `declare` with appropriate flags, or `local -r`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the steps where all the objects the user/role owns must be dropped and any privileges must be revoked for any role has been granted.

From PostgreSQL manual (The DROP USER is an alias for DROP ROLE):

> A role cannot be removed if it is still referenced in any database of the cluster; an error will be raised if so. Before dropping the role, you must drop all the objects it owns (or reassign their ownership) and revoke any privileges the role has been granted. The REASSIGN OWNED and DROP OWNED commands can be useful for this purpose.
>
> However, it is not necessary to remove role memberships involving the role; DROP ROLE automatically revokes any memberships of the target role in other roles, and of other roles in the target role. The other roles are not dropped nor otherwise affected.

Use the REASSIGNED OWNED or DROP OWNED command.

Try adding below command somewhere before the DROP USER command:

`DROP OWNED BY $username CASCADE;`

Reference:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-droprole.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-drop-owned.html